# How to run shell commands with variables in Jenkinsfile

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, sh, jenkins-groovy

I want to run below commands in Jenkins file as pipeline on multiple servers to fetch report I am new to Jenkins and wants to know how I can write Jenkins file

Shell command:
HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
DATE=$(date "+%d-%m-%y %H:%M:%S")
CPUUSAGE=$(top -b -n 1 -d1 | grep "Cpu(s)" |awk '{print $2}' | awk -F. '{print $1}')
MEMUSAGE=$(free |grep Mem |awk '{print $3/$2 * 100.0}')

What I have tried :

```
pipeline {  
agent {label 'server1,server2'}
     environment {
        def CPUUSAGE=0;
        def MEMUSAGE=0;
        
    }
    stages {
    stage('Check System Usage') {
        steps {
            script {
                 CPUUSAGE = sh '''"top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}'", returnStdout: true).trim()'''
                 MEMUSAGE = sh '''"free -m | awk 'NR==2{printf "%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2 }'", returnStdout: true).trim()'''
                 END { printf( "\n" ); }'", returnStdout: true).trim()'''
                 println("CPUUSAGE = ${CPUUSAGE}","MEMUSAGE = ${MEMUSAGE}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

please help
Thanks
Sama

Answer (score 1):

```
pipeline {  
  agent {label 'server1,server2'}
  environment {
    def CPUUSAGE=0;
    def MEMUSAGE=0;
  }
  stages {
    stage('Check System Usage') {
      steps {
        script {
          def  CPUUSAGE_SCRIPT = '''
            top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf "%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}'
          '''

          def MEMUSAGE_SCRIPT = '''
            free -m | awk 'NR==2 {printf "%.2f%%\t\t", $3*100/$2} END {printf "\n"}'
          '''
          CPUUSAGE = sh(script: CPUUSAGE_SCRIPT, returnStdout: true).trim()
          MEMUSAGE = sh(script: MEMUSAGE_SCRIPT, returnStdout: true).trim()

          println("CPUUSAGE = ${CPUUSAGE}, MEMUSAGE = ${MEMUSAGE}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Yong 

I am getting below error, tried to add \ before " but its not helping 

top -bn1 | grep load | awk '{printf \"%.2f%%\t\t\n", $(NF-2)}'


+ top -bn1
+ grep load
+ awk '{printf "%.2f%%  
", $(NF-2)} END {printf "
"}'
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%.2f%%  
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ unterminated string
awk: cmd. line:1: {printf "%.2f%%  
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error

any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Check this one:

```
pipeline {  
agent any
     environment {
        CPUUSAGE = sh(script: 'top -bn1 | grep load', returnStdout: true).trim()
        MEMUSAGE = sh(script: 'free -m', returnStdout: true).trim()
    }
    stages {
        stage('Check System Usage') {
            steps {
                echo "CPUUSAGE = $CPUUSAGE"
                echo "MEMUSAGE = $MEMUSAGE"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But you need to check your full script. These shorted scripts work for me.